# Displaying appropriate button in each product depending on if the product is inside the user's cart

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a bunch of products that I read from my database (MySQL) and I store/add them to an ArrayList of type product and output this list to a Recycleview trough an adapter. However, each product displayed, has two images (functioning as buttons) one of them invisible and one visible. Those two buttons are an add icon and a remove icon. The plan is that if the product is inside the cart, the image with the add icon is set to invisible while the other one is set to visible.

My database contains tables for `products` (with columns such as `id`, `title`, etc), for the `users` (with columns such as `id`, `username`,etc) and for the `cart` (with columns such as `id`, `product_id`, `user_id`).

When I initially display the list with all the products how can I know which ones are inside the user's cart and set respectively the visible of the images for each products?

Do I need to perform some kind of join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could `LEFT JOIN` the `products` table with the `carts` table:

```
SELECT p.id, p.title, c.id
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN carts c ON c.product_id = p.id AND c.user_id = ?
```

When a product is not in the cart, `c.id` will be `NULL` (else, it will contain the `id` of the cart record).